# PCIe SATA Card for x16 slot

Tags: pcie, sata

I need to add a few HDDs to my desktop. There are various PCIe SATA cards for up to 8 SATA ports.

My problem is that almost all of them use X1 PCIe slot. While you can reach the SATA maximum speed of 6.0 Gbit/s with PCIe 3.0 x1, the speed is very low if all HDDs are used at the same time.

On the other hand, I use a PCIe x16 slot of my motherboard (whether the card is x1 or x16).

I found a few options on Amazon for PCIe x8 cards for 4 SATA ports, which can reach the maximum SATA speed for 2.4 bands (2.4 x 6.0 Gbit/s), but they do not seem very popular.

Is there any PCIe SATA Card using all bands provided by PCIe x16?

Comment: Using more PCIe lanes is about performance in this case, and I think the products for that aren't popular because in the current idiom of storage, you go for SSD for performance, and HDD for pure volume.  That doesn't mean I don't understand you wanting to get the most performance out of the HDDs, its just that once you start spending hundreds of dollars on RAID cards for this, if performance matters, then people now spend that high$ money on SSD, so the market for performance SATA/HDD dwindles a bit. Doesn't change  your need, but changes what products are on the market.

Comment: @WilburWhateley The need for using more PCIe lanes makes more sense for SSDs since they have lower capacity than HDDs, and thus, you need to use a higher number of SATA connections (say, 4 x 4TB SSD instead of 1 16TB HDD).